# Customized keyboard layout ignores AltGr key [14.04]

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, cyrillic

For some reason I want to change my Russian layout so that I put stress mark (U+0301, like hére) by pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+Yo, in a pretty similar way to other languages' layouts.

So there I go, making a subtle modification in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ru`:

```
//  key <TLDE> {    [     Cyrillic_io,     Cyrillic_IO  ]   }; default
    key <TLDE> {    [     Cyrillic_io,     Cyrillic_IO, U0301   ]   }; // stress mark added over Yo
```

Rebooting the computer, doesn't work. System still sees no difference between <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. Then, observing other layouts, I came up with further edit:

```
key.type[group1]="FOUR_LEVEL";

include "level3(ralt_switch)" // for the sake of having AltGr+Yo as stress mark
```

No success either, behavior is exactly the same. Do you have any idea how to make system recognize between <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (or the problem is somewhere else, though I doubt it)?